# How to link taxonomy and views in a succinct way?

Tags: views, 8, taxonomy-terms

[image]So here is my use case: I have taxonomy vocabularies titled accommodation, and in the vocabulary, there are 4 terms.

- hotel
- motel
- campground
- guest housing

I want to create a view that displays in a page that has these four terms as menu links that once you click the link all content nodes containing that taxonomy term are listed. I have been struggling with this.

My main Block is creating a menu from taxonomy and linking it to the view(I would like to use a custom URL), I have tried the [Taxonomy Menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu) module, which is close, but cannot figure how to configure it correctly, I have gotten closest creating an attachment display within the view. I am so close.

Comment: What's the problem with https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu module?

Comment: I can create the requisite taxonomy menus, however, it seems the config options or placement of the config options have changed since the 8.x-3.3 and they have seemingly not updated documentation. The docs suggest that all routing config is available at structure>taxonomy>edit vocabularies , I am not finding that is the case in drupal 8.

Comment: You can't solve your problem with a view of taxonomy terms? If you make click over the terms you will go to the term page and you will see all the related nodes. Maybe I missing something.

Comment: I can't get the point. Can you provide some mockups?

Comment: I will try to include some in my post

Comment: Is better if you do it. I know how to solve your problem only with views. But I far from my laptop at this moment.

Answer (score 1):

Forget views here and write a few lines of own code here. I had this problem also recently. Views is much to unflexible. You must do the following:

1. Create a route to your controller method
2. Get all relevant nodes in the method
3. Create a template via hook_theme() for the output.
4. Realize all your details! ;)

I needed around ~1 hour for this.

Comment: Thanks, I am fairly green concerning Drupal and PHP. can you illustrate what this would look like. I am using Drupal 8.

Comment: If you are new to Drupal, then learn Drupal. Nobody will type the code for you for free. Sad but true. Check https://www.drupal.org/project/examples and buy a book about Drupal 8. Check routing, database queries + entity queries and taxonomies. My Permissions by Term module has also a lot of examples. Check the code.

Comment: Not looking for anybody to type code for me but, it's just my learning style I like looking at similar examples, then I adapt for my own uses, as I research topics to gain a deeper understanding along the way. I have solved this particular issue using views. After a little research and some mentorship, I found the fault was attempting to do everything using one view. My use case can be executed using two views one as taxonomy view and the second a content view. I will elaborate in an answer to this post.

Comment: Also thanks for pointing toward those topics I will research those.